# Duplicate XML entry | Hibernate orm.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm

Here is an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at ru.leon0399.podius.home.Core.run(Core.java:39)
    at ru.leon0399.podius.home.Core.main(Core.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate XML entry for ru.leon0399.podius.common.entity.AbstractEntity
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.addClass(XMLContext.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.addDocument(XMLContext.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 4 more
```

And here is my orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
<mapped-superclass class="ru.leon0399.podius.common.entity.AbstractEntity">
    <attributes>
        <id name="uuid">
            <column name="uuid" column-definition="BINARY(16)"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="createdAt">
            <column name="created_at" updatable="false"/>
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="updatedAt">
            <column name="updated_at"/>
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
```

And here is my AbstractEntity class

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Creatable, Updatable, Entity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2544875895016856663L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractEntity.class);

    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    private Date updatedAt;

    private Date createdAt;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, there is no duplicates

After debugging, i understand, that file `orm.xml` was read TWICE!
Here is a screenshot with confirmation of this idea

[image]

So how can i tell Hibernate DO NOT read this file twice?

Comment: i guess `AbstractEntity` isnt annotated as MappedSuperclass right?

Comment: Can you show us the AbstractEntity class?

Comment: @aksappy I've updated my topic

Comment: @Apostolos I didn't annotated any class with any annotation in code

Answer (score 4):

This is an old issue, but might be a current problem as well as was for me...

I was having exactly the same issue and had just figured out that if I remove the reference in `persistence.xml` to the `orm.xml` file, it stops happening.

`<mapping-file>./META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>`

Or if I rename it to `mapping.xml` instead of `orm.xml` and remap it at `persistence.xml` it also works.

`<mapping-file>./META-INF/mapping.xml</mapping-file>`

It seems that Hibernate looks for such a file (`orm.xml`) by default and does not prevent that from being loaded twice in case of `persistence.xml` is already mentioning it.

Thus, just rename it and remap it, or easier, remove the reference in `persistence.xml`.