# Why do I get "Duplicate XML entry" when I try to run my jHipster app as a stand-alone war (built by gradlew bootRepackage)?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, jhipster, gradlew

I am stumped by this one so I'm looking for some help here.

I am developing a jHipster app with multiple database connections, built with gradle. The app runs fine with "./gradlew bootRun" but when I try to package a stand-alone war with "./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage" and run it, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/babycenter/belle/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate XML entry for com.babycenter.belle.readonly.domain.InvoiceLineItem
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at com.babycenter.belle.BelleApp.main(BelleApp.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate XML entry for com.babycenter.belle.readonly.domain.InvoiceLineItem
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.addClass(XMLContext.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.addDocument(XMLContext.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I am puzzled because the file it says the error is in, DatabaseConfiguration.java, should only read entities from the package com.babycenter.belle.domain, which the class/XML it says is duplicated, InvoiceLineItem, is not in.

Here are files that may be involved. Tell me if you would like to see another.

**DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
package com.babycenter.belle.config;

import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants;
import io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase;

import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.babycenter.belle.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private final Environment env;

    public DatabaseConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                     LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

        // Start Liquibase asynchronously
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor, env);
        // Start Liquibase synchronously
        //SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
        } else {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.babycenter.belle.domain")
            .persistenceUnit("readwrite")
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

**ReadOnlyDatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
package com.babycenter.belle.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "roEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "roTransactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.babycenter.belle.readonly.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ReadOnlyDatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadOnlyDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Bean(name = "roDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-ro")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "roEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean roEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("roDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return
            builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.babycenter.belle.readonly.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("readonly")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "roTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager roTransactionManager(@Qualifier("roEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory roEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(roEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

**InvoiceLineItem.java**

```
package com.babycenter.belle.readonly.domain;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * An object representation of a row from the opr_invoice_line_item table in Redshift
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "opr_invoice_line_item", schema = "advertising")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class InvoiceLineItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "invoice_line_item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long invoiceLineItemId;

    @Column(name = "sales_order_line_item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long salesOrderLineItemId;

    @Column(name = "primary_performance", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long primaryPerformance;

    @Column(name = "third_party_performance", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long thirdPartyPerformance;

    @Column(name = "invoice_units", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String invoiceUnits;

    @Column(name = "invoice_amount", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Float invoiceAmount;

    /**
     * Assigned when possible - not a column in opr_invoice_line_item table
     */
    private String billingPeriodName;

    public Long getInvoiceLineItemId() {
        return invoiceLineItemId;
    }

    public void setInvoiceLineItemId(Long invoiceLineItemId) {
        this.invoiceLineItemId = invoiceLineItemId;
    }

    public Long getSalesOrderLineItemId() {
        return salesOrderLineItemId;
    }

    public void setSalesOrderLineItemId(Long salesOrderLineItemId) {
        this.salesOrderLineItemId = salesOrderLineItemId;
    }

    public Long getPrimaryPerformance() {
        return primaryPerformance;
    }

    public void setPrimaryPerformance(Long primaryPerformance) {
        this.primaryPerformance = primaryPerformance;
    }

    public Long getThirdPartyPerformance() {
        return thirdPartyPerformance;
    }

    public void setThirdPartyPerformance(Long thirdPartyPerformance) {
        this.thirdPartyPerformance = thirdPartyPerformance;
    }

    public String getInvoiceUnits() {
        return invoiceUnits;
    }

    public void setInvoiceUnits(String invoiceUnits) {
        this.invoiceUnits = invoiceUnits;
    }

    public Float getInvoiceAmount() {
        return invoiceAmount;
    }

    public void setInvoiceAmount(Float invoiceAmount) {
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
    }

    public String getBillingPeriodName() {
        return billingPeriodName;
    }

    public void setBillingPeriodName(String billingPeriodName) {
        this.billingPeriodName = billingPeriodName;
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7"
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.11"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility=1.8
targetCompatibility=1.8
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'idea'
defaultTasks 'bootRun'

group = 'com.babycenter.belle'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ''

bootRepackage {
   mainClass = 'com.babycenter.belle.BelleApp'
}

war {

}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.babycenter.belle.BelleApp'
    executable = true
    buildInfo()
}

if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        appendix = 'pathing'

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                    it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/').replaceAll(' ', '%20')
                }.join(' ')
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        addResources = false
        dependsOn pathingJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/java/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
        }
    }
} else {
    bootRun {
        addResources = false
        systemProperties System.properties
    }
}

//use jrebel to hot-deploy class changes during development
if (project.hasProperty('rebelAgent')) {
    bootRun.jvmArgs += rebelAgent
}

test {
    include '**/*UnitTest*'
    include '**/*IntTest*'

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task cucumberTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/CucumberTest*'

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

test.finalizedBy(cucumberTest)

task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test
    reportOn cucumberTest
}

cucumberTest.finalizedBy(testReport)

apply from: 'gradle/docker.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/liquibase.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/mapstruct.gradle'
//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
} else if (project.hasProperty('stag')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_stag.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}

if (project.hasProperty('graphite')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/graphite.gradle'
}

if (project.hasProperty('prometheus')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/prometheus.gradle'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://nexus.babycenter.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/'}
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.github.jhipster:jhipster:${jhipster_server_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jcache:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:${dropwizard_metrics_version}"
    compile "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:${logstash_logback_encoder_version}"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:${jackson_dataformat_csv_version}"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    compile ("com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:${metrics_spring_version}")
    compile "javax.cache:cache-api"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernate_version}"
    compile ("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:${hikaricp_version}")
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commons_lang_version}"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:${commons_io_version}"
    compile "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
    compile "org.ehcache:ehcache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:${hibernate_version}"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:${hibernate_version}"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernate_version}"
    compile ("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    compile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:${liquibase_slf4j_version}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    compile "org.zalando:problem-spring-web:${problem_spring_web_version}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors"
    compile ("org.springframework:spring-context-support")
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfox_version}") {
        exclude module: 'mapstruct'
    }
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:${springfox_version}"
    //The Data Warehouse (i.e. our read-only data source) is AWS Redshift
    compile "com.amazon.redshift:RedShiftJDBC42:${redshift_jdbc_version}" //needs the RedShiftJDBC42 driver to work
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:${redshift_sdk_version}"
    //our writable database is mysql
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstruct_version}"
    testCompile "org.awaitility:awaitility:${awaitility_version}"
    testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:${cucumber_version}"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:${cucumber_version}"
    testCompile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }
    testCompile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertj_version}"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:${liquibase_slf4j_version}"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library"
    testCompile "com.h2database:h2"
    optional ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${spring_boot_version}") {
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional dependencies here
}

clean {
    delete "target"
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/resources'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1'
}

task stage(dependsOn: 'bootRepackage') {
}

if (project.hasProperty('nodeInstall')) {
    node {
        version = "${node_version}"
        npmVersion = "${npm_version}"
        yarnVersion = "${yarn_version}"
        download = true
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn cleanResources,bootBuildInfo
bootBuildInfo.mustRunAfter cleanResources
```

Here are my versions of things:

jHipster 4.9.0

Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE

Gradle 4.2

Groovy 2.4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve this myself.

I was using annotations in code to define my JPA entities PLUS an orm.xml file for named queries that had to have my result class entities defined. I had no persistence.xml file.

This ran fine with “./gradlew bootRun” but when I bundled a war it threw the exception listed above.

I learned when I package up a Spring Boot war with Hibernate JPA it will attempt to add annotated entities to orm.xml - and may even load orm.xml multiple times:

[Duplicate XML entry | Hibernate orm.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298667/duplicate-xml-entry-hibernate-orm-xml/41271500#41271500)

Since I already had an entity definition there, it said there was a duplicate.

Basically I learned I can either use annotations in code, including named queries, OR define everything in orm.xml but I can’t mix the two.